# How can you determine if I certain parameter exists when adding values?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I haven't worked with SQL in a really long time but a new project is requiring I get my hands dirty with it. I'm building a SELECT statement from a few textboxes on my page and started to write the code to add parameter values when it occurred to me that not every parameter might get used.

For example:

```
    string parameterizedQuery = " SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE ";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountNumber.Text.Trim()))
        parameterizedQuery += " AccountNumber = @AccountNumber";

    //5 more instances of similar query building for other fields

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(parameterizedQuery, sqlconn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", txtAccountNumber.Text.Trim());
```

But it's possible that `@AccountNumber` won't make its way into the query if the user isn't searching with that field. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I know that's a really subjective question but I feel like I cannot being doing this correctly or efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can create just an empty command object right away, and fill it with params as needed:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string parameterizedQuery = " SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE ";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAccountNumber.Text.Trim()))
{
    parameterizedQuery += " AccountNumber = @AccountNumber";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", txtAccountNumber.Text.Trim());
}
...
cmd.CommandText = parameterizedQuery;
```

Comment: you may add "1==1" at the end of parameterizedQuery's initial value so if txtAccountNumber is null it'll execute anyway. Also adding conditions to parameterizedQuery have to start with "  AND " so it'll be ok.

Comment: In the past, changing the CommandText property of a command object has cleared the Parameters collection. However, it was a long time ago that I observed this behavior, and it's not documented either way. It may have been fixed since then, so no downvote, but I'm still skeptical this will work.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, interesting, never heard of that before. Let me check the docs for what it does nowadays

Comment: I'm interested to hear the results of your test... it was 2005 or so when I first noticed this, and I've just avoided the problem ever since. If it's changed, I'd like to know :)

Comment: One more thing: [I really don't like AddWithValue()](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, docs do not say anything about it indeed. In fact, I see no evidence of such behavior in [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,525) either. Will give it an actual try once I have Windows at hand, but it seems that if there was such a bug, it is gone now

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
string sql = " SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE 1=1";
var pars = new List<SqlParameter>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAccountNumber.Text))
{
    parameterizedQuery += " AND AccountNumber = @AccountNumber";
    var par = new SqlParameter("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
    par.Value = txtAccountNumber.Text;
    pars.Add(par);
}

//5 more instances of similar query building for other fields

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn);
if (pars.Length > 0) cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars.ToArray());
```

Comment: that's exactly what i've meant.

Comment: Does `AddRange` accept a list? You might need `ToArray` here

Comment: I've used the 1=1 technique since at least 2005. I fixed the missing AddRange(). Still waiting for the day when all of those AddRange() methods are updated to allow IEnumerable<T>. I had a couple other issues in the first draft, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cmd.Parameters.Contains("@parameters"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameters", Parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.